# My Scrapy code is just crawling(Debug:Crawled(200)) but not scraping any data

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

My Scrapy code is just crawling the links on the webpage but not Scraping any data.Actually,I'm trying to scrape some data about Coronavirus pandemic for my project(like country name,cities within that country and then no. of cases,casualties etc.).The output is Debug:Crawled(200) in the cmd. I'm trying to scrape it from worldometers website(Being a newbie to scrapy i don't know much and for output reference the image link is provided)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
import logging

class CountriesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'countries'
    allowed_domains = ['www.worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['http://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/']

def parse(self, response):
    countries = response.xpath("//td/a")
    for country in countries:
        country_name = country.xpath(".//text()").get()     
        country_link = country.xpath(".//@href").get()
        #To access the country link
        absolute_url = response.urljoin(country_link)
        yield scrapy.Request(url = absolute_url,callback = self.parse_country)     #Or do directly-->  yield response.follow(url = country_link)

def parse_country(self,response):
    rows = response.xpath("(//table[@class = 'table table-bordered table-hover table-responsive usa_table_countries dataTable no-footer'])[1]/tbody/tr")
    for row in rows:
        city = row.xpath(".//td[1]/text()").get()
        cases = row.xpath(".//td[2]/text()").get()
        deaths = row.xpath(".//td[4]/text()").get()
        active_cases = row.xpath(".//td[6]/text()").get()

        yield {
        "City":city,
        "Total_Number_of_Cases": cases,
        "Deaths":deaths,
        "Active_Cases":active_cases
        }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ye8UC.png)

Comment: your `rows` xpath is wrong, this xpath should get you the rows `'//*[contains(@id,"countries_today")]//tr'`

Comment: it might be of help for you to use https://css-selector-to-xpath.appspot.com/ in order to get the correct xpath, since css selectors are imho easier to make - table.class1.class2.classn for your rows for example.